# How to create a file in python having name = ".gitignore"

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to create a file without a name in python (only filetype)

I tried this -

```
open(".gitignore","w+").close()
```

But it does not work.

edit - it does work real issue is in getting file through glob.glob

```
classify_folder_name = #path of the folder which contain .gitignore file
rel_paths = glob.glob(classify_folder_name + '/**', recursive=True)

for local_file in rel_paths:
  print(local_file)
```

it does not print .gitignore file.

Any help will be appreciated.
Note -: don't want to use os.listdir()

Comment: *it does not work*? what does that mean? no file was created?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? I think it _does_. You may not _see_ that file, if your don't have dotfiles showing.

Comment: @jonrsharpe there is no such file with this name in my directory even after executing this code.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist yeahh, no file was created. 
NOTE - I tried this on google colab.

Comment: did you look in the correct directory (i.e. the current working directory)? did you make sure you displayed hidden files?

Comment: The file was either created, or the code threw an exception. Prove to yourself that either did or did not happen, and show those results with an [edit]. SO is a terrible debugger, so you will have to do this yourself. Hint: show how you determine the file is or is not present. Think about the current working directory as well as the notion of dot-files.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things that you might check:

- files with dot at the beginning are hidden so whatever OS you are using, make sure you have hidden files visibility enabled
- It might be saved in different directory

> ```
> open(".gitignore","w+").close()
> ```

It would be better if you do this:

To create a file:

```
with open('.gitignore', 'w') as fp:
    pass
```

Comment: I am using Colab i verified .

open(".gitige","w").close()
import os
os.listdir(os.getcwd())

['.config', '.gitignre', '.gitignore', '.gitige', 'sample_data']